# It is possible to send HTTP response when the analysis is finished on SonarQube?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-api

I am integrating TFS 2015 with SonarQube 6.1, and I need to know when the analysis are finished to run another process.

I have had a look at some triggers called hooks, but it required develop a plugin for SonarQube.

Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SonarQube 6.2 offers the ability to register up to 10 URLs at the global level and an additional 10 at the project level to be POSTed to once the analysis report has been processed server-side.